# Как обратиться к объекту класса Form1 из наследуемого класса?

Tags: c#, winforms

В наследуемом классе WordPerformer есть статический метод, который обращается к чек боксу главной формы, но появляется ошибка, требующая для "Form1.сheckBox1" ссылку на объект. Как обратиться к объекту формы в таком случае? Вызываю метод с помощью `WordPerformer.CheckWord();`

Comment: Статические методы не имеют доступа к полям экземпляров. Если вам надо что то сделать с формой в статическом методе, передайте форму в него как параметр.

Comment: Подсказки современных IDE достаточно информативны, чтобы понимать почему у вас возникает та или иная проблема при сборке. Научитесь их понимать.